# CORS issue with SignalR - Origin not allowed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, cors

So I've read up on all the previous questions on this, but following the steps don't seem to be working for me. I'm getting the "Origin * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin", but that doesn't make sense to me. If I open the same request in Chrome in it's own tab, and look at the network tab, I see the following CORS headers intact. Also, the hubs generate just fine. I'm using Web API, .NET 4.5, and the rc2 of SignalR. I also tried removing the Allow-Credentials in the web.config, but that didn't help either.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with,X-CustomAuth,Content-Type,X-Impersonate
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,HEADER
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

I've also set `jQuery.support.cors` to `true`, even though it was already as true, I'm using JQuery 1.9, and here's my connection to the server and hub:

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://myserver/api/signalr';
    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling', xdomain: true });
```

I've also tried this to connect, both with same issue.

```
    $.connection('http://myserver/api/signalr/echo').start(function () {
      console.log('Connected');

      $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        $log.info('Connected to hub.');
      });          
    });
```

Comment: To make things even stranger, I used the sample code from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ to load up and try a url in the same app as the signalr, so the same url but /api/admin/someoperation, and it loads up just fine, but when I try the url for signalr, get the cross origin issue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` value cannot be used with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `true`. Try either one of the following:

1. Drop the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header entirely.
2. Change the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from `*` to the actual value of the `Origin` header.

#1 might be easier to do, but #2 is required if you need to support cookies.

Comment: I tried removing the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials value already, it didn't seem to help. I'll give it another shot though.

Comment: Is SignalR adding the Allow-Credentials and origins on its' own? I was looking at it with Fiddler, and the headers are sometimes duplicated, but only on the requests to SignalR, so I removed my definitions in the web.config, and it may be working, I'm at least connecting now. This is an issue for me though, as it means the rest of my app will have CORS problems.

Comment: Going to go ahead and mark this, but it seems odd that SignalR adds these headers and CORS values on its' own, I saw an issue to disable it by default on GH, but I guess that's not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc, you should **NOT** be using **jQuery.support.cors**

> Don't set jQuery.support.cors to true in your code.

Link to the official doc: [official doc](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)